# Ordering tuple to get max of tuple item

Tags: python

How would I get the episode_id of the item with the highest season_number?

```
items = [(episode_id, season_number), (1234, 1), (3131, 0), (88, 2)]
episode_num_of_highest_season_number(items) = 88
```

I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
sorted(items, key=item[1])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
import operator
print(sorted(items, key=operator.itemgetter(1))[-1][0])
```

which indeed sorts by the second element in each tuple and return the first value of that highest-ranked item (which is then located at the end of the list).

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
sorted(l, key=lambda item: -item[1])[0][0]
```

Here is some more information:

https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the maximum, then no need to sort.  Just use the `max()` function with an appropriate key:

```
from operator import itemgetter
max(items, key=itemgetter(1))[0]
```

[`operator.itemgetter(i)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) is equivalent to the function `lambda x: x[i]`.